# How to add UIButton Programmatically from a NSObject Class

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I am trying to create a UIButton in a `NSObject` class. I get the error " Use of unresolved identifier view. I figured that it needs to have `UIViewController` for it to work.

is there a work around so that I create multiple buttons with just this on multiple view controllers. what am I missing?

```
func createButton () {
    let button = UIButton();
    button.setTitle("Add", forState: .Normal)
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.blueColor(), forState: .Normal)
    button.frame = CGRectMake(15, -50, 200, 100)
    view.addSubview(button)
}
```

Comment: import UIKit Framework in your NSObject Class

Comment: i have imported both Foundation & UIKit, still get the error

Comment: ok if you are creating and adding button in NSObject class then you have to pass the reference of ViewController in which you want to show this button..! Hope it help? If not please add some more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare method definition with parameter-argument in which you want to add button :

```
func createButton (view:UIView) {
    let button = UIButton();
    button.setTitle("Add", forState: .Normal)
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.blueColor(), forState: .Normal)
    button.frame = CGRectMake(15, -50, 200, 100)
    view.addSubview(button)
}
```